# Named Entity Recognition RegexNER add more columns for information

Tags: stanford-nlp

There is a way to do this ?

Add another column to the regexner.mapping file that describes some aspect of the named entity, for example:

Bachelor of Engineering    DEGREE       2.0   some_data_information_1

Lalor    LOCATION    PERSON    2.0    some_data_information_2

Labor
       ORGANIZATION        2.0    
    some_data_information_3

The idea is that when the Entity Mention is detected this information will be accessible, for example `some_data_information` could be a key from another database or anything.

```
List<CoreMap> entityMentions = document.get(MentionsAnnotation.class);

for (CoreMap entityMention : entityMentions) {
  //get the information in the description column...
  entityMention.get( ... );
}
```

This can be done ?

Answer (score 0):

RegexNER does not support that type of functionality at this time.  You could write TokensRegex rules that do that though.

```
# make all patterns case-sensitive
ENV.defaultStringMatchFlags = 0
ENV.defaultStringPatternFlags = 0

# these Java classes will be used by the rules
ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }
nerInfo = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NERInfo" }
tokens = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TokensAnnotation" }

# define some regexes over tokens
$COMPANY_BEGINNING = "/[A-Z][A-Za-z]+/"
$COMPANY_ENDING = "/(Corp|Inc)\.?/"

# rule for recognizing company names
{ ruleType: "tokens", pattern: ([{word:$COMPANY_BEGINNING} & {tag:"NNP"}]+ [{word:$COMPANY_ENDING}]), action: (Annotate($0, ner, "COMPANY"), Annotate($0, nerInfo, "COMPANY_INFO")), result: "COMPANY_RESULT" }


// replace "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NERInfo" with a class you define (that class does not exist, I just list it as an example.)
```

Full details on using TokensRegex here: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html

Comment: Hi,  thanks a lot for your answer.  I will try it to see if it's enough to my needs.  I'm also testing other tools like GATE to do the same.  I 'm doing some benchmarking of text mining frameworks.